# How to display only one specified div in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, element, display

I am trying to display one specified div when I am clicking on button with class .showFormButton, but unfortunetly every div with class .showForm appears. How to make only one .showForm div appear using jQuery?
JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".showFormButton").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".showForm").css('display', 'block');
$(".showForm").css('position', 'absolute');
});
});
```

HTML

```
print "<input type='submit' class='showFormButton' VALUE='Ulubiony' onclick='ShowDiv()'>";

    print "<div style='display: none; margin-left: -170px; margin-top: -60px; background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(15, 159, 220),rgb(14, 108, 148));' class='showForm'>";
        print "<div >";
            print "<p><b>Dodaj do ulubionych pracownika</b></br> [".$row['imie1']. " ".$row['nazwisko1']."]</p>";
            print "<p>Osobista notatka</p>";
            print "<FORM ACTION='view_tm.php' METHOD='POST' ENCRYPT='multipart/form-data' name='ulubiony_pracownik_dodaj'>";
            print "<textarea name='id_pracownik_op_notatka' rows='10' cols='45'>". $row['notatka'] ."</textarea>";
            print "<input type='hidden' name='id_pracownik_op' value='" . $row['id_pracownik'] . "'>";
            print "<INPUT TYPE='submit' id='showFormButton' NAME='ulubiony_pracownik' VALUE='Dodaj do ulubionych'>";
            print "</form>";
        print "</div>";
```

Comment: how would you like to distinguish the div , i mean by index or some other attributes

Comment: Can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this` object to target your selection over the clicked element,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".showFormButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var elm = $(".showForm", this)
     elm.css({'display' : 'block', 'position' : 'absolute' });
   });
});
```

Instead of using `.css()` for setting the properties, you could use `.addClass()`. Because it would be easy in maintaining, like removing the added properties in future.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".showFormButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var elm = $(".showForm", this)
     elm.addClass("clicked");
   });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.clicked { display:block; position:absolute; }
```

---

**Edit:**

Since the target element is the next sibling the the current element, you have to use [`.next(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) at this context.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".showFormButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var elm = $(this).next(".showForm")
     elm.css({'display' : 'block', 'position' : 'absolute' });
   });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding 'this' to my code is not working - div is not appearing.

Comment: It seems that I cannot apply my css to the div object.

Comment: @BartoszBrożek I thought that the target element was a descendant, I just updated the answer, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `.show()` function to make hidden stuff visible. Take a look at this code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.action-btn', function () {
        $('.hidden-div').show();
    });
));

<div style="display: none;" class="hidden-div">
    Hidden text
</div>

<button class="action-btn">Show hidden div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the div by using an attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".showFormButton").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".showForm[showme='1']").css('display', 'block');
$(".showForm[showme='1']").css('position', 'absolute');
});
});
```

HTML

```
print "<input type='submit' class='showFormButton' VALUE='Ulubiony' onclick='ShowDiv()'>";

    print "<div showme='1' style='display: none; margin-left: -170px; margin-top: -60px; background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(15, 159, 220),rgb(14, 108, 148));' class='showForm'>";
        print "<div >";
            print "<p><b>Dodaj do ulubionych pracownika</b></br> [".$row['imie1']. " ".$row['nazwisko1']."]</p>";
            print "<p>Osobista notatka</p>";
            print "<FORM ACTION='view_tm.php' METHOD='POST' ENCRYPT='multipart/form-data' name='ulubiony_pracownik_dodaj'>";
            print "<textarea name='id_pracownik_op_notatka' rows='10' cols='45'>". $row['notatka'] ."</textarea>";
            print "<input type='hidden' name='id_pracownik_op' value='" . $row['id_pracownik'] . "'>";
            print "<INPUT TYPE='submit' id='showFormButton' NAME='ulubiony_pracownik' VALUE='Dodaj do ulubionych'>";
            print "</form>";
        print "</div>";
```